# How to cast generics in a loop?

Tags: java, generics, casting, coding-style

```
public static void someMethod(List < ? extends BaseDto > list) {
    for (ChildDto dto : list) {

    }
}
```

ChildDto extends BaseDto and here I'm sure its the list full of ChildDto.

I do know I can do something like this

```
for (TextApplicationDto dto : (List<TextApplicationDto>)list) {
```

but it does not look pretty.

Is there any better way of doing the casting?

Comment: In my opinion there's something good in the fact that it's not pretty - you should avoid casts since they make your code less type-safe. When a cast looks ugly you're less inclined to use it.

Comment: IMHO, you should not cast like this. Such a cast produces a warning for a good reason. Doing it like gabuzo suggested looks much better for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way would be:

```
public static void someMethod(List < ? extends BaseDto > list) {
    for (BaseDto dto : list) {
        ChildDto taDTO = (ChildDto)dto;
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

It also allows you to use `instanceof` to be sure that the list only contains `ChildDto`

Answer (score 3):

> `ChildDto` extends `BaseDto` and here I'm sure its the list full of `ChildDto`.

Then why doesn't the argument type of that method represent that knowledge?

It should be `List<ChildDto>` or even `List<? extends ChildDto>`.

The way you cast it is one solution, you can also cast each returned value on its own. Both are equally "nice" in that they will fail at roughly the same position:

```
for (BaseDto bDto : list) 7
  ChildDto dto = (ChildDto) bDto;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: because I would have to pass List<ChildDto> and I will get compilation error saying that it can't cast List<? extends BaseDto> to List<ChildDto> in a lot of places. I would like to deal with casting in that class. Its not like List < ? extends BaseDto > is always List of ChildDto, but in this method its always.